# Problems efficently computing the roots of a multiple argument function

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

Hello my dear intelligent people on the internet,

I want to compute the roots of a (non invertible) two argument function in a given interval using scipy.optimize.fsolve:

```
kappa = 1.4

def Av_ma(Ma):
    Ma[np.where(Ma < 0)] = 0
    return Ma * ((2 + (kappa - 1) * (Ma ** 2)) / (kappa + 1)) ** ((kappa + 1) / (2 * (1 - kappa)))


def Av_ma_root(Ma, _Av_e_2):
    return Av_ma(Ma) - _Av_e_2
```

The actual funtion Av_ma has only one argument, but I want to compute the roots for values of _Av_e_2 between 0 and 1. As a result i want an array containing only the root sets for like 100 values of _Av_e_2.
This is how my code is looks so far:

```
Av_e_2 = np.arange(0, 1 + 1e-12, 0.01)
x0 = np.arange(0.1, 1, 0.1)
    
startvec = np.repeat(x0, len(Av_e_2))
lAv_e_2 = np.tile(Av_e_2, np.shape(x0)[0])
pv2 = optimize.fsolve(Av_ma_root, startvec, args=lAv_e_2)
pv2 = np.reshape(pv2, (len(x0), len(Av_e_2)))
pv2 = np.round(pv2, 6)
pv2 = np.array([np.unique(p) for p in np.transpose(pv2)])
print(pv2)
```

I define an array of the 'starting estimate' array with the length of the Av_e_2.
Its used to give fsolve the same starting estimate for every value of Av_e_2.

There after i define an array of the values of Av_e_2. Its used to give fsolve every single value of Av_e_2

After optimizing I reshape, round and throw out the non-unique values.

In short: my code doesn't work. It does not produce the solution i want it to

```
test_vec_opt.py:25: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.

pv2 = np.array([np.unique(p) for p in np.transpose(pv2)])
```

Comment: Post a stack trace please and use a debugger. The error messages are important, but so is the location of the error.

Comment: I updated the post. the error message fom before was due to me trying to plot the solution. It now does kinda work (see new error message, no traceback available), but it wont produce the output I want.

Comment: The warning does not include a traceback.  Look at the problem expression piece by piece.